# Sampling frequency in bilinear transform when designing butterworth filter

Tags: filter-design, butterworth

I'm trying to design digital Butterworth filter from scratch. First I use `butterap` to design an analog prototype to get zeros, poles and gain

```
[za, pa, ka] = buttap(n);
```

Here I set `n = 5` for example and then convert it to transfer function to check its frequency response

```
[b, a] = zp2tf(za, pa, ka);
freqs(b, a);
```

[image]

From the figure above I know it's a lowpass filter with cutoff frequency $\Omega_c=1$.

Now I want to convert this analog filter to a half-band lowpass digital filter using bilinear transform, according to the documentation of MATLAB's `bilinear`.

```
% Strip any zeros at infinity
za = za(isfinite(za));
% Do bilinear transformation
pd = (2 * fs + pa) ./ (2 * fs - pa);
zd = (2 * fs + za) ./ (2 * fs - za);
kd = real(ka * prod(2 * fs - za) ./ prod(2 * fs - pa));
% Add extra zeros at -1 so the resulting system has equivalent numerator and denominator order.
zd = [zd; -ones(length(pd) - length(zd), 1)];
```

Then convert it to transfer function and look at the frequency response

```
[b, a] = zp2tf(zd, pd, kd);
figure; freqz(b, a);
```

My question is about the sampling frequency $f_s$. I want a half-band lowpass filter meaning that $\omega_c = 0.5\pi$. From the relationship between digital frequency and analog frequency $\omega = \Omega T$ I can derive that $T = 0.5\pi\ \text{s}$ and $f_s = 1/T = 2/\pi\ \text{Hz}$. The following figure shows the frequency response when I set `fs = 2/pi`

[image]

Apparently it doesn't have a -3 dB attenuation at $\omega = 0.5\pi$. Only when I set `fs = 0.5` can I get the desired result:

[image]

Anyone can help me to find where am I wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bilinear transform has a nonlinear frequency mapping
$$
\varOmega = \frac{2}{T}\tan{\frac{\omega}{2}}
$$
Substituting $\varOmega = 1$ and $\omega = 0.5\pi$ into it and you can derive that
$$
T = 2
$$
and thus
$$
f_s = 0.5
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!